# test iOS certificate and app

Tags: ios, push-notification

I need to write a program to send PUSH notification messages to `iOS` devices. The app is going to be created by a third-party company and it is not yet complete. Is there a free test app I can have on my phone with an available certificate with which I can test sending PUSH messages? All the tutorials I found assume I already have my certificate but I do not have one.

Answer (score 0):

As Push Notification mechanism on iOS depends on Apple servers, you cannot send notification by bypassing Apple. Therefore, unfortunately you cannot send/test push feature without having a proper certificate.

To be precise: you need to have a APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) certificate which is connected to your particular app id. Basically all you need is a Apple Developer account.

Comment: if i have the certificate for the app and my own device id, will i be able to send a message to the target app or do i need anymore information?